# How back state to default in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, frontend

I Have this code in React Native

```
 class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.initialState={
        backGroundColor: '#ffffff',
        visible:[true,true,true,true,true,true],
        progress:0,
        numbers: shuffle([1,2,3,4,5,6])
    }
    this.state = this.initialState;
  }
  _resetState(){
     this.setState(this.initialState);
   }

  _change(teste,op){
    if(op==this.state.numbers[0]){
      let array = this.state.visible;
      switch(op){
        case 1:
          array[op-1] = false;
          break;
        case 2:
          array[op-1] = false;
          break;
        case 3:
          array[op-1] = false;
          break;
        case 4:
          array[op-1] = false;
          break;
        case 5:
          array[op-1] = false;
          break;
        case 6:
          array[op-1] = false;
          break;
      }
      this.setState({backGroundColor: teste,visible:array,progress: this.state.progress+0.16666666666666});
      this.state.numbers.splice(0,1);
    }else{
      console.log(this.initialState);
    }
  }
```

When I do console.log(this.initialState) the arrays numbers and visible inside the state is not the initial but the backGroundColor and progress are the initial values. Why this happened? How can i keep their initial values ? I need back to initial state all elements (including the two arrays) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your constructor, you could assign a *copy* of your initialState instead of the original object, ie.:

```
this.state = Object.assign({}, this.initialState);
```

I don't know React well enough to know if this is the best pattern for re-initialising state, but it should work.